# Erro ao iniciar a aplicação utilizando PM2 com propriedades customizadas em pedido expresso

Tags: node.js, express.js

neste diretório defini no arquivo index.d.ts algumas propriedades customizadas na Request do express que serão utilizadas por um middleware de autenticação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode ser visto na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, ao iniciar a aplicação com PM2 recebo o seguinte erro:

**src/middlewares/ensureAuthentication.ts(34,13): error TS2339: Property 'authenticatedUserId' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'**

O que devo fazer para resolver este problema ?

Este é meu tsconfig:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem algum motivo para rodar a aplicação em TS sem transpilar para JS? Ou seja, qual o impedimento do PM2 rodar a aplicação gerada pelo build (tsc)?

Answer (score 0):

Tive um problema com PM2 usando typescript recente, se caso quando você inicia a aplicação normalmente ele executa, você pode usar a abordagem de startar o pm2 fazendo ele rodar o seu script de start da aplicação, ex:

pm2 start npm --name "nomeapppm2" -- run {script_name}